# Does Anyone Like Movies?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

What two movies am I going to watch this weekend?

---

1. `GAMMD---------------------{02}SI`
2. `FMDIDGAD------------------{02}GWTW`
3. `MASLWLABOCYNKWYGG---------{01}FG`
4. `YGNABB--------------------{04}J`
5. `YTTM?---------------------{06}TD`
6. `MNIIMYKMFPTD--------------{09}TPB`
7. `IOAFW---------------------{06}MPATHG`
8. `HLVB----------------------{08}T2`
9. `KYFCBYEC------------------{04}TG2`
10. `MTFBWY--------------------{04}SW`
11. `IBB-----------------------{04}T`

---

12. `IHWSH---------------------{05}WHMS`
13. `TIGAFWNIKA----------------{05}TWOO`
14. `TFROFCI:YDNTAFC-----------{06}FC`
15. `YCHTT!--------------------{02}AFGM`
16. `HLAYK---------------------{05}C`
17. `ISDP----------------------{07}TSS`
18. `TNCIB!--------------------{02}ALOTO`
19. `GYCFIHTITWR---------------{12}DS(O:HILTSWALTB)`
20. `WWGHIFTC------------------{10}CHL`

### So, **Which two movies am I going to watch this weekend?**

Hint:

> The numbers are there for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the full solution. With GentlePurpleRain's great findings...

> The numbers simply point to a letter in each movie title (2nd, 2nd, 1st etc.); once anagrammed, they reveal the 2 chosen movies (which are already on the list): The first batch anagrams into **FORREST GUMP** and the second batch anagrams into **FIGHT CLUB**.

Comment: You went ahead and made my day, in spite of the typo. For your effort, I'll add a +50 bounty to your answer when I am able. (fixed the typo, btw)

Comment: @Chowzen Very kind of you! Re-edited mine too. Love the quiz :)

Answer (score 8):

### Partial answer

I've figured out what the lists refer to, but I haven't figure out how to get the movie names from them yet:

> These are all initialisms of famous movie quotations:
>
> 1. Go ahead, make my day! (*Sudden Impact*)
>
>    Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn . (*Gone With the Wind*)
>
>    Mama always said, "Life is like a box of chocolates.  You never know what you're gonna get." (*Forrest Gump*)
>
>    You're gonna need a bigger boat! (*Jaws*)
>
>    You talking to me?  (*Taxi Driver*)
>
>    My name is Inigo Montoya.  You killed my father.  Prepare to die. (*The Princess Bride*)
>
>    It's only a flesh wound! (*Monty Python and the Holy Grail*)
>
>    Hasta la vista, baby. (*Terminator 2*)
>
>    Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer. (*The Godfather 2*)
>
>    May the Force be with you. (*Star Wars*)
>
>    I'll be back (*(The) Terminator*)
>
>    ---
>
>    I'll have what she's having! (*When Harry Met Sally*)
>
>    Toto, I've got a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore... (*The Wizard of Oz*)
>
>    The first rule about Fight Club is: You do not talk about Fight Club. (*Fight Club*)
>
>    You can't handle the truth! (*A Few Good Men*)
>
>    Here's looking at you, kid! (*Casablanca*)
>
>    I see dead people. (*The Sixth Sense*)
>
>    There's no crying in baseball! (*A League of Their Own*)
>
>    Gentlemen, you can't fight in here! This is the War Room! (*Doctor Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb*)
>
>    What we've got here is failure to communicate. (*Cool Hand Luke*)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that all of these are on AFI's 100 Years...100 Movie Quotes, though darned if I know what that alludes to.  https://www.afi.com/100years/quotes.aspx

Comment: @Exal This is not the source (#6, at least, is not on the linked page). This said, the actual source is not needed for a final answer.

Comment: oooooooops my mistake for not checking every quote.

Comment: Could the numbers refer to specific letters in the answers. Perhaps {02} means there isn't a letter in the quote but the second letter in the movie title is to included, and {11} means the 1st letter of the quote and the first letter of the title? Then collect all these letters and they may spell out the title(s) of movies (or their anagrams). Or something similar to this.